# In R and reporttools: Can I suppress 'all' category of grouped stats produced by tableContinuous?

Tags: r, latex, reporttools

I'm working with the `tableContinuous` function of the `reporttools` package in R.

Everything works as expected and using some example from [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/reporttools/docs/tableContinuous):

```
library("reporttools")
data(CO2)
vars <- CO2[, 4:5]
group <- CO2[, "Treatment"]
weights <- c(rep(1, 60), rep(0, 10), rep(2, 14))

tableContinuous(vars = vars, weights = weights, subset = 
                  c(rep(TRUE, 57), rep(FALSE, 100 - 57)), group = group, prec = 3, print.pval = 
                  "kruskal", cap = "Table of continuous variables.", lab = "tab: descr stat")
```

I get a table as expected:

[image]

Is it possible to remove the `all` lines from the output?

Comment: Could somebody with a higher rep please add `reporttools` tag perhaps?

Comment: Do you want to keep cells with p-values in these lines?

Comment: @Julius Would be nice to keep them, but not the top priority for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such an option is not available in `tableContinuous`. The `all` lines are omitted only in case if there is only one level per variable, i.e. see `if (n.levels == 1) ...` at the end of the source of `tableContinuous`.

However, this problem can be solved using regular expressions. I am not an expert in it so there might be better ways.

```
library(reporttools)
data(CO2)
vars <- CO2[, 4:5]
group <- CO2[, "Treatment"]
weights <- c(rep(1, 60), rep(0, 10), rep(2, 14))

result <- tableContinuous(vars = vars, weights = weights, subset = 
                            c(rep(TRUE, 57), rep(FALSE, 100 - 57)), group = group, prec = 3, print.pval = 
                            "kruskal", cap = "Table of continuous variables.", lab = "tab: descr stat")
```

Completely removing `all` lines:

```
cat(gsub("\\\\hline\n[^\n]+& all &[^\n]+\n", "", result))
```

Keeping p-values:

```
greg <- gregexpr("p (=|<) [^\n]+", result)
regmatches(result, greg) <- list(gsub("(?<=&)[-.\\w ]+", " ", 
                                     regmatches(result, greg)[[1]], perl = TRUE))
cat(result)
```

Comment: @radek, is there anything I could add to my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry for late feedback. Finally had time to work with your code. First solution works without a flaw. Using the second solution I also get the correct output, however, when generating kniting pdf file less than symbol for p value is not displayed correctly. Could you please point me to relevant part of code I need to change (I guess `<` should be replaced with LATEX's `\textless`?)

Comment: @radek, is it only the symbol `<` that is wrong? I guess that the lines with `p <` were not removed at all. I updated my answer now by changing `gregexpr("p =` to `gregexpr("p (=|<)` to fix that. It now also includes a case with negative numbers (changed `[.\\w ]+` to `[-.\\w ]+`). In case you still want to change `p <` to `p \textless` try `gsub("p <", "p \\\\textless", result)`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Updated solution still doesn't want to print `<` correctly. Also - when you change the option of `reporttolls` from ` print.pval = "kruskal"` to ` print.pval = "anova"` it messes up with LATEX code and doesn't display correctly formatted table in pdf document.

Comment: Is `<` printed correctly before applying modifications from my answer? I can't help with `print.pval = "anova"` either, because using this option in your example does not ruin anything for me. So you will have to give me some more details.

Comment: No it wasn’t printed correctly either. `anova` issues are socondary to me at the moment so please ignore this issue.

Comment: If it wasn't printed correctly, then I can't really help here since it seems to be more related to knitr. As I mentioned in the previous comment, in case you find what to replace `<` with, you could additionally use `gsub` after all the other modifications.

Comment: All right then - I understand. Priority for me is table without p now and that you sorted perfectly. So thanks again for your effort! =)